# how can I make the code here choose a new song file when the previous one ends?

Tags: loops, audio, processing

I have been struggling to develop a solution for this, and I really want this part to be excellent for turn-in. However, I'm having issues specifically with the .isPlaying() function, as it won't see that it's over already. Plus, it will "stack" the sound if I don't have a noLoop() in there. This combo of one function not working properly and one being a necessity for it to play a song correctly makes it difficult to figure out how to make the computer re-pick a song and then play that. I know there has to be a solution for this, but I can't find it myself, especially when I'm under a time crunch. I honestly might leave it if no-one replies in time, as I'm somewhat cool with how it's working now and will "adapt" to it, but I still want to find a solution to this that doesn't involve installing yet another library.

```
        import processing.sound.*;
        
        SoundFile dd1;
        SoundFile dd2;
        SoundFile dd3;
        SoundFile dd4;
        SoundFile dd5;
        SoundFile dd6;
        int s = int(random(1, 6));
    
        int bs=0;
        int PT=0;
    
    void setup() {
    size(20,20);
    
    dd1 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-1.wav");
    dd2 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-2.wav");
    dd3 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-3.wav");
    dd4 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-4.wav");
    dd5 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-5.wav");
    dd6 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-6.wav");
    
    void draw(){
        if (second()-PT>=1) {
    PT=second();
    bs +=1;
  }
  println(bs);
  if (bs>=10) {

    if (s==1) {
      noLoop();
      dd1.play();
    }
    if (dd1.isPlaying()==false) {
      s=int(random(1, 6));
    }
    if (s==2) {
      noLoop();
      dd2.play();
    }
    if (dd2.isPlaying()==false) {
      s=int(random(1, 6));
    }
    if (s==3) {
      noLoop();
      dd3.play();
    }
    if (dd3.isPlaying()==false) {
      s=int(random(1, 6));
    }
    if (s==4) {
      noLoop();
      dd4.play();
    }

    if (dd4.isPlaying()==false) {
      s=int(random(1, 6));
    }
    if (s==5) {
      noLoop();
      dd5.play();
    }
    if (dd5.isPlaying()==false) {
      s=int(random(1, 6));
    }
    if (s==6) {
      noLoop();
      dd6.play();
    }
    if (dd6.isPlaying()==false) {
      s=int(random(1, 6));
    }

    if (keyPressed) {
      if (key=='w'||key=='a'||key=='s'||key=='d'||key== ' ') {
        loop();
        if (dd1.isPlaying()) {
          dd1.stop();
          loop();
        }
        if (dd2.isPlaying()) {
          dd2.stop();
          loop();
        }
        if (dd3.isPlaying()) {
          dd3.stop();
          loop();
        }
        if (dd4.isPlaying()) {
          dd4.stop();
          loop();
        }
        if (dd5.isPlaying()) {
          dd5.stop();
          loop();
        }
        if (dd6.isPlaying()) {
          dd6.stop();
          loop();
        }
        s=int(random(1, 6));
        bs=0;
        loop();
      }
    }
  }

    void mouseMoved() {
    
    
      if (dd1.isPlaying()==true) {
        dd1.stop();
      }
      if (dd2.isPlaying()==true) {
        dd2.stop();
      }
      if (dd3.isPlaying()==true) {
        dd3.stop();
      }
      if (dd4.isPlaying()==true) {
        dd4.stop();
      }
      if (dd5.isPlaying()==true) {
        dd5.stop();
      }
      if (dd6.isPlaying()==true) {
        dd6.stop();
      }
      s=int(random(1, 6));
      bs=0;
      loop();
    }
```

Comment: Part of the difficulty here is that you are trying to achieve something that should be approached with an Array of SoundFile objects. My advice would be to scale this back first to just two sounds

Comment: Also, a re-indent of this sample code would likely be appreciated by the community and in doing so you'll also see that there are a couple of missing brackets in the code provided

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a number of separate issues which will stop the given code sample from working as well as hindering you from finding a solution, which include:

- variable naming
- style
- incorrect syntax
- repetition

Once you address these one-by-one you should hopefully see a solution

### Syntax and Style

Addressing the syntax errors and inconsistent indentation gives us this code:

```java
import processing.sound.*;

SoundFile dd1;
SoundFile dd2;
SoundFile dd3;
SoundFile dd4;
SoundFile dd5;
SoundFile dd6;

int s = int(random(1, 6));

int bs=0;
int PT=0;

void setup()
{
  size(20, 20);

  dd1 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-1.wav");
  dd2 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-2.wav");
  dd3 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-3.wav");
  dd4 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-4.wav");
  dd5 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-5.wav");
  dd6 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-6.wav");
}

void draw()
{
  if (second()-PT>=1)
  {
    PT=second();
    bs +=1;
  }
  println(bs);
  if (bs>=10)
  {
    if (s==1)
    {
      noLoop();
      dd1.play();
    }
    if (dd1.isPlaying()==false)
    {
      s=int(random(1, 6));
    }
    if (s==2)
    {
      noLoop();
      dd2.play();
    }
    if (dd2.isPlaying()==false)
    {
      s=int(random(1, 6));
    }
    if (s==3)
    {
      noLoop();
      dd3.play();
    }
    if (dd3.isPlaying()==false)
    {
      s=int(random(1, 6));
    }
    if (s==4)
    {
      noLoop();
      dd4.play();
    }

    if (dd4.isPlaying()==false)
    {
      s=int(random(1, 6));
    }
    if (s==5)
    {
      noLoop();
      dd5.play();
    }
    if (dd5.isPlaying()==false)
    {
      s=int(random(1, 6));
    }
    if (s==6)
    {
      noLoop();
      dd6.play();
    }
    if (dd6.isPlaying()==false)
    {
      s=int(random(1, 6));
    }

    if (keyPressed)
    {
      if (key=='w'||key=='a'||key=='s'||key=='d'||key== ' ')
      {
        loop();
        if (dd1.isPlaying())
        {
          dd1.stop();
          loop();
        }
        if (dd2.isPlaying())
        {
          dd2.stop();
          loop();
        }
        if (dd3.isPlaying())
        {
          dd3.stop();
          loop();
        }
        if (dd4.isPlaying())
        {
          dd4.stop();
          loop();
        }
        if (dd5.isPlaying())
        {
          dd5.stop();
          loop();
        }
        if (dd6.isPlaying())
        {
          dd6.stop();
          loop();
        }
        s=int(random(1, 6));
        bs=0;
        loop();
      }
    }
  }
}

void mouseMoved()
{
  if (dd1.isPlaying()==true)
  {
    dd1.stop();
  }
  if (dd2.isPlaying()==true)
  {
    dd2.stop();
  }
  if (dd3.isPlaying()==true)
  {
    dd3.stop();
  }
  if (dd4.isPlaying()==true)
  {
    dd4.stop();
  }
  if (dd5.isPlaying()==true)
  {
    dd5.stop();
  }
  if (dd6.isPlaying()==true)
  {
    dd6.stop();
  }
  s=int(random(1, 6));
  bs=0;
  loop();
}
```

We can use this as the basis for the remainder of this answer.

### Variable Naming

It would be wise to choose another convention for your variable names to

1. make to program easier fo you to comprehend
2. make it easier for other to work out what is happening

Here is a table of suggested alternatives

| Original | Suggestion |
| --- | --- |
| `s` | `currentSoundIndex` |
| `bs` | `secondsSinceUserInput` |
| `PT` | `previousTimeInSeconds` |
| `SoundFile dd#` | `SoundFile[] daydreams` |

I will use the suggestions for the remainder to make the answer a little more legible.

### Repetition

Let's address the repetition next. If you find yourself writing variable names with a number at the end, it is a heavy implication that the process could be simplified.

What would make sense is to bundle the individual `SoundFile` objects into a single `SoundFile[]` array

The setup

```java
SoundFile dd1;
SoundFile dd2;
SoundFile dd3;
SoundFile dd4;
SoundFile dd5;
SoundFile dd6;

void setup()
{
  size(20, 20);

  dd1 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-1.wav");
  dd2 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-2.wav");
  dd3 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-3.wav");
  dd4 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-4.wav");
  dd5 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-5.wav");
  dd6 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-6.wav");
}
```

becomes

```java
SoundFile[] daydreams;

void setup()
{
  size(20, 20);
  daydreams = new SoundFile[6];

  for (int i = 0; i < daydreams.length; i++)
  {
    daydreams[i] = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-"+str(i+1)+".wav");
  }
}
```

The `mouseMoved` event

```java
if (dd1.isPlaying()==true)
{
  dd1.stop();
}
if (dd2.isPlaying()==true)
{
  dd2.stop();
}
if (dd3.isPlaying()==true)
{
  dd3.stop();
}
if (dd4.isPlaying()==true)
{
  dd4.stop();
}
if (dd5.isPlaying()==true)
{
  dd5.stop();
}
if (dd6.isPlaying()==true)
{
  dd6.stop();
}
```

becomes

```java
for (SoundFile daydream : daydreams)
{
  if (daydream.isPlaying())
    daydream.stop();
}
```

which in itself implies that this could be wrapped into a function

```java
void stopAllSounds()
{
  for (SoundFile daydream : daydreams)
  {
    if (daydream.isPlaying())
      daydream.stop();
  }
}
```

Triggering and generating a new random sound

```java
if (s==1)
{
  noLoop();
  dd1.play();
}
if (dd1.isPlaying()==false)
{
  s=int(random(1, 6));
}
if (s==2)
{
  noLoop();
  dd2.play();
}
if (dd2.isPlaying()==false)
{
  s=int(random(1, 6));
}
if (s==3)
{
  noLoop();
  dd3.play();
}
if (dd3.isPlaying()==false)
{
  s=int(random(1, 6));
}
if (s==4)
{
  noLoop();
  dd4.play();
}

if (dd4.isPlaying()==false)
{
  s=int(random(1, 6));
}
if (s==5)
{
  noLoop();
  dd5.play();
}
if (dd5.isPlaying()==false)
{
  s=int(random(1, 6));
}
if (s==6)
{
  noLoop();
  dd6.play();
}
if (dd6.isPlaying()==false)
{
  s=int(random(1, 6));
}
```

becomes

```java
for (int i = 0; i < daydreams.length; i++)
{
  if (currentSoundIndex == i)
  {
    noLoop();
    daydreams[i].play();
  }
  if(!daydreams[i].isPlaying())
  {
    currentSoundIndex = int(random(6));
  }
}
```

### Current problems

Jumping around using `noLoop()` and `loop()` makes the behaviour of the above a little trickier to predict so I would recommend scrapping it altogether.

What I can see is an inherent problem in the central draw loop where you decide which sound should play

```java
for (int i = 0; i < daydreams.length; i++)
{
  if (currentSoundIndex == i)
  {
    noLoop();
    daydreams[i].play();
  }
  if(!daydreams[i].isPlaying())
  {
    currentSoundIndex = int(random(6));
  }
}
```

Written as it was previously is a little hard to see, but in this form we can determine one potential problem. When the above is first run what you do is

1. check which sound you *should* be playing then play it
2. check if all other sounds are not playing
3. if any subsequent sound is not playing generate a new random number to determine which sound should play.

Let's step through an example

- we start with `currentSoundIndex = 5`
- for `i = 0`

  - `currentSoundIndex` does not equal `0` so we don't play `daydreams[0]`
  - we then check if `daydreams[0]` is playing, which it definitely isn't
  - as a result we generate a random number and assign to `currentSoundIndex`
  - by chance `currentSoundIndex` now equals `1`
- we repeat this for `i = 1`

  - `currentSoundIndex` ***does*** `1` so we start playing `daydreams[1]`
  - we then check if `daydreams[1]` is playing. It is, so we do nothing
- we repeat this for `i = 2`

  - `currentSoundIndex` does not equal `2` so we don't play `daydreams[2]`
  - we then check if `daydreams[2]` is playing, which it definitely isn't
  - as a result we generate a random number and assign to `currentSoundIndex`
  - by chance `currentSoundIndex` now equals `3`
- we repeat this for `i = 3`

  - `currentSoundIndex` now ***does*** equal `3` so we start playing `daydreams[3]`
  - we then check if `daydreams[3]` is playing, it is, so we do nothing
- we repeat this for `i = 4`

  - `currentSoundIndex` does not equal `4` so we don't play `daydreams[4]`
  - we then check if `daydreams[4]` is playing, which it definitely isn't
  - as a result we generate a random number and assign to `currentSoundIndex`
  - by chance `currentSoundIndex` now equals `5`
- we repeat this for `i = 5`

  - `currentSoundIndex` now ***does*** equal `5` so we start playing `daydreams[5]`
  - we then check if `daydreams[5]` is playing, it is, so we do nothing

Some variation of this will happen every single time. `noLoop()` and `loop()` may mitigate some of it. What i would suggest is a slightly different approach. Since the files are now arranged in an array, we know the index of the file to play so we no longer need a loop. What we do need is some indication of when to generate a new random `currentSoundIndex` and when to play that file. for that I would suggest introducing one more variable, a single `boolean` that I will call `soundShouldPlay`.

`soundShouldPlay` starts off as `true` and could be used in some way like the following

```java
if (secondsSinceUserInput >= 10)
{
  if (soundShouldPlay)
  {
    daydreams[currentSoundIndex].play();
    soundShouldPlay = false;
  }

  if(!daydreams[currentSoundIndex].isPlaying())
  {
    currentSoundIndex = int(random(6));
    soundShouldPlay = false;
  }
}
```

If `soundShouldPlay` is true we play `daydreams[currentSoundIndex]` and set `soundShouldPlay` to `false`. No now next time we come round, since `soundShouldPlay` is false we never ask to play `daydreams[currentSoundIndex]` again. Once `daydreams[currentSoundIndex]` is no longer playing we generate a `currentSoundIndex` and set `soundShouldPlay` back to `true`. As a result, next time we come back round, since `soundShouldPlay` is `true`, we play the new `daydreams[currentSoundIndex]`.

### Put it altogether

Putting that altogether would give a program looking like

```java
import processing.sound.*;

int currentSoundIndex = int(random(6));
int secondsSinceUserInput = 0;
int previousTimeInSeconds = 0;
boolean soundShouldPlay = true;

SoundFile[] daydreams;
void setup()
{
  size(20, 20);
  daydreams = new SoundFile[6];

  for (int i = 0; i < daydreams.length; i++)
  {
    daydreams[i] = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-"+str(i+1)+".wav");
  }
}

void draw()
{
  if ((second() - previousTimeInSeconds) >= 1)
  {
    previousTimeInSeconds = second();
    secondsSinceUserInput += 1;
  }
  println(secondsSinceUserInput);
  if (secondsSinceUserInput >= 10)
  {
    if (soundShouldPlay)
    {
      daydreams[currentSoundIndex].play();
      soundShouldPlay = false;
    }

    if(!daydreams[currentSoundIndex].isPlaying())
    {
      currentSoundIndex = int(random(6));
      soundShouldPlay = false;
    }
  }
}


void keyPressed()
{
  if (key=='w'||key=='a'||key=='s'||key=='d'||key== ' ')
  {
    stopAllSounds();
    currentSoundIndex = int(random(6));
    secondsSinceUserInput = 0;
  }
}

void mouseMoved()
{
  stopAllSounds();
  currentSoundIndex = int(random(6));
  secondsSinceUserInput = 0;
}

void stopAllSounds()
{
  for (SoundFile daydream : daydreams)
  {
    if (daydream.isPlaying())
      daydream.stop();
  }
}
```

The manner in which you deal with user input in this case is questionable, but without further indication of your intentions it is difficult to give any kind of feedback.

Answer (score 1):

@fdcpp's answer is comprehensive and very well explained (+1).
In my opinion it's the right answer.

I would like to simply contribute a few simpler snippets that may help get familiar with the Processing `SoundFile`.

If `isPlaying()` doesn't correctly report `false` when a sound has finished playing a workaround is to call [`percent()`](https://processing.github.io/processing-sound/processing/sound/AudioSample.html#percent()):

```
import processing.sound.*;
SoundFile file1;
SoundFile file2;

void setup() {
  // load two files
  file1 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-1.wav");
  file2 = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-2.wav");
  // play first one
  file1.play();
}

void draw(){
  // check if the first file finished playing 
  if(file1.percent() >= 99.8){
      println("track pretty close to done: cue out / cross fade here");
      file1.stop();
      // move file 2 playhead to start
      file2.jump(0);
      // play file 2
      file2.play();
   }
   // same check for file 2
   if(file2.percent() >= 99.8){
      println("track pretty close to done: cue out / cross fade here");
      file2.stop();
      // move file 2 playhead to start
      file1.jump(0);
      // play file 2
      file1.play();
   }

   background(0);
   text("file1.percent(): " + file1.percent() + "\n" + 
        "file1.percent(): " + file2.percent(),5,15);
}
```

As fccpp mentions, arrays are excellent to avoid repeating yourself and making the code bloated and hard to navigate and edit:

```
import processing.sound.*;
// total audio files
int NUM_FILES = 6;
// array of sound files
SoundFile[] playlist = new SoundFile[NUM_FILES];
// index of the currently playing sound file
int currentIndex = 0;

void setup() {
  // load files
  for(int i = 1 ; i <= NUM_FILES; i++){
    playlist[i] = new SoundFile(this, "daydream-" + i + ".wav");
  }
  // play first one
  playlist[currentIndex].play();
}

void draw(){
  // check if the first file finished playing and play next sound
  if(hasCurrentSoundFinished()){
    playNextSound();
  }

  background(0);
  text("current sound percent: " + playlist[currentIndex].percent(), 5,15);
}

boolean hasCurrentSoundFinished(){
  return playlist[currentIndex].percent() >= 99.8;
}

void playNextSound(){
  // stop current sound
  playlist[currentIndex].stop();
  // increment the index
  currentIndex++;
  // check if it's past the last index to optionally loop to first sound
  if(currentIndex == NUM_FILES){
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  // reset playhead position
  playlist[currentIndex].jump(0);
  // play
  playlist[currentIndex].play();
}
```